# Ways to initialize STL containers, C-style arrays

Tags: stl, initialization

I have seen standard arrays being initialized with `{{0}}`, e.g. `std::array<size_t, 3> dim = {{0}}`.

Is this an standard approach? Can I use the same approach to reinitialize? That is to say

```
void foo(std::array<size_t, 3>& dim)
{
   dim = {{0}};
}
```

Can I use the same method to initialize a C-style array? For example

```
void foo(size_t dim[3])
{
   dim = {{0}};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use it on c-style array/structures because c-style array has no assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

`std::array<size_t, 3> dim = {{0}}` initializes std::array from braced-init-list (abbreviated as {}-list).

It is a form of list-initialization as explained here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization. Note that any type which provides a constructor taking std::initializer_list will also allow initialization from braced-init-list since the C++ language maps {}-list to std::initializer_list.

The statement `dim = {{0}};` will invoke copy-list-initialization as explained here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

However, `size_t dim[3]; dim[3] = {{0}};` will result into error because size_t type does not provide a constructor taking std::initializer_list.